# Can an IIS serve a webpage without a website configured?

Tags: iis, web-config

Scenario:

Currently I have an IIS Server which holds the following websites:

-test1.local - Binded to 10.0.0.10:443(https)

-test2.local - Binded to 10.0.0.11:443(https)

-test3.local - Binded to 10.0.0.12:443(https)

Recently I've created a DNS entry of "test4.local" to point at test3's IP of 10.0.0.12. The Idea is that I can use a second DNS entry to point to the same IP address that test3.local uses. I keep getting a "Connection_Reset" in my browser and not sure exactly whats going on here.

My question is - Can this configuration actually work without creating an actual site or do I need to make a website called "test4.local" in the IIS server and bind it to whatever IP to make it work?

Comment: There can be no connection if no valid site bindings are available, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html#background You showed not enough info about existing bindings above, but you should be able to tell yourself whether they cover test4.local. BTW, which IIS version are you using? IIS 8 and above has SNI support, where you don't need new IP addresses at all for HTTPS sites.

Comment: By default, if you don't have SNI with mutiple https websites. Then IIS would probably send the wrong certificate for your website. However, if you are hosting the application in IIS 8 or higher version. Then Server name indication can be checked. In this case, you can bind test3.local and test4.local for the same site. You don't need to afraid the SSL certificate verification get mixed up and you also don't need to create another website.